# CoreText method for ShowTextAtPoint(float x, float y, string text) MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, cgcontext, core-text

I'm updating an app to iOS 7 that uses the depreciated ShowTextAtPoint method and can't seem to find the proper way to use CoreText instead of ShowTextAtPoint.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?